# I want to label a table for reference purpose. Can someone tell me what is the command for this?

Tags: tables

How can I label a table and then refer it to my latex file?

Comment: You already found the right terms. Search for label and ref in a LaTeX introduction.

Comment: 'caption' to include a caption and number.  'label'  to assign a key that you can then refer to using for example ' ref'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use caption for the `\caption`, `\label{xy}` and `\ref{xy}`. See [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing)

A working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Animals}
 Table \ref{table:animals} <my text>
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline 
            Animals & Results \\ 
            \hline 
            Dog & 4 \\ 
            \hline 
            Cat & 9 \\ 
            \hline 
            Bird & 15 \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Animals}
        \label{table:animals}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a correct reference counting use `\ref` after `\caption`.
optional: The package `hyperref` produce hypertext links for cross-referencing (a clickable link is also created).
[hyperref reference](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)